# How to translate "mention bien" and "mention très bien" in English?

Tags: translation

I'm applying to universities. I was thinking to translate "mention bien/très bien" by "with honors" but on my transcripts I had both (on different diplomas), so I would like to know if I can distinguish them

Comment: Your question needs reformatting. Start with an introduction of what "mention bien/très bien" is, then ask your question. Someone who starts reading is completely baffled, until (s)he is at 80% and then it starts to make some sense.

Comment: This is a question that might fit better on the Academia site, where a somewhat similar question is https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/114019/if-i-got-1-0-for-master-thesis-in-germany-can-it-be-summa-cum-laude-in-my-cv. It is unwise to attempt your own translation because there is the risk that you will be perceived as overstating your qualification.

Comment: For the UK: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_France#The_UK_Honors_degree_system_compared_to_grades_in_France and https://www.southampton.ac.uk/uni-life/international/your-country/europe/france.page and for the US https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/bac-baccalaur%C3%A9at-avec-mention-assez-bien.276441/

Comment: @Mari-LouA There would be no difference here in US/UK usage.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

les mentions on French diplomas (funnily enough, I happen to have three of them) means honors. (Not to be confused with mention on legal documents, please.)

Translators (which is what I am) **argue a lot about this**. Personally, I would used: degree in [subject] with high honors and with highest honors. I also have a mention très bien.

with honors, high honors, highest honors.

I will, however, point out that those terms work for university degrees. If this is for the BAC, and you use the term baccalaureate diploma (for le BAC, baccalauréat) you can use them. I advise against using "high school diploma" with those terms. The BAC= A Baccalaureate diploma (equivalent to high school plus two years).

[please note: I was **thinking of** translating x as y.

[honors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_grading_in_France)

Comment: Downvoters, please. You are doing a disservice to the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This should be treated as specific and technical terminology associated with a particular educations and examinations system, and *not translated*. You should treat the full qualification name as a proper noun. You would not "Translate" *Jacques* to *James*. Nor should you translate *Baccalauréat mention bien* to "Bachelor degree with honours".

In a Resumé or CV you list your qualifications exactly as you received them "A diploma *mention bien*" And you may indicate by means of a footnote or endnote an equivalence with the local examination system "*equivalent to a diploma with high honours". You do this as a courtesy and convenience to the person receiving your CV.

Hiding the actual qualification behind a translation could cause you to be accused of misrepresenting your qualification and lead to difficult questions at interview.

Comment: I'm sorry but this is not so. In English, you can say with honors etc. and put the French in brackets. I speak from experience.

Comment: I'll take you disagreement, but agree with you that translators argue about such things a lot.  I think the difference between our answers is that I say "diplôme mention bien (Diploma with honours)" and you say "Diploma with honours (diplôme mention bien)  The problem with this comes when people try to "Translate" a *Baccalaureate* into "A levels". But the systems are so different that translation fails.  I stand by my answer.  *Don't translate qualification names. Treat them as proper nouns*.

Comment: Yes, I always say: Baccalaureate degree. Because the word can actually be used in English. And people just have to know it. That said, I do not think one has to mention the French at all, really. I don't always on mine.

Comment: Not really.  I know what a Bachelor's degree is.  I don't really know what a "Baccalaureate degree" might be.  Is it Secondary school?  Higher? Postgraduate level?

Comment: Europeans know it and US universities know it when people apply from European countries. The BAC, French secondary school, which for the US, is HS plus two years. I have no idea about the UK and what I would use there....

Comment: That is another problem.  If you translate to "English" you face the problem that the words used in the England are completely different from the USA.  Heck, the education system in Scotland is completely different from that in England and Wales.  England has GCSEs, A-levels, three year Bachelor degrees and one year master degrees, plus an increascing number of undergraduate master degrees.  Scotland is different.  USA is different.  Even something as simple as translating "BA" from AmE to BrE is fraught with difficulties. I get asked if I have a "four year degree": do I lie?

Comment: French Baccalaureate Degree (undergraduate).

Answer (score -1):

Just chiming in here, and SEVERAL years too late, but saying that "The BAC= A Baccalaureate diploma (equivalent to high school plus two years)" is absolutely incorrect.
The French BAC is a test taken at the end of high school. In the US, for example, we have three years of Junior HS (collège in France) and four years of high school (as opposed to three in France). It all works out in the end to the same number of years in school.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/128428)

Comment: junior college is only two years. And the BAC is more than a HS diploma. It is actually more like a HS diploma plus one or two more years, level-wise.